# Use Scanner class to replace all occurrence of string with another

Tags: java

i want to scan a string with a `Scanner` class and i want to replace each "is" word by "is not" expect  embedded "is " like "this" for example
`good morning this is my name` became `good morning this is not my name`
i write the snippet of code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String chaine="good morning this is my name";

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(chaine);

    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        String word=sc.next();

        if(word.equals("is")) 
            chaine=chaine.replace(word, "is not");

    }
    System.out.println(chaine);
}
```

when i execute this program it print:
`good morning this not is not my name` but i want to print good morning `this is not my name`

Comment: Why use a `Scanner` at all? Why not just `chaine = chaine.replace("is", "is not");`?

Comment: Well, `replace(...)` will look for _all_ occurences of that word and since "is" is part of "this" you'll get the replacement there. I'd suggest using the regex based method `replaceAll()` along with the regex `\bis\b` to match "is" _only_. If you want to keep using `replace(...)` and the scanner (I assume for learning purposes) you could surround the word with whitespace, i.e. `replace(" " + word + " ", " is not ");` to match and replace `" is "`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for before I did not see what you exactly want. I modify a little your code. I use StringBuilder to store the parts of the words and I close the Scanner.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String chaine="good morning this is my name";
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(chaine);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        String word=sc.next();

        if(word.equals("is")) 
        {
            sb.append("is not");
        }
        else
        {
            sb.append(word);
        }
        //Add space after every added word.
        sb.append(" ");
    }

    sc.close();
    String result = sb.toString();
    //Call trim to remove the space after the last word
    System.out.println(result.trim());
}
```

Good Luck to all!

Comment: Why would this fix the OP's problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have attached a solution to your problem. It's a similar approach with the correction from the solution already been submitted. Consider the use case where the user will type "Good morning this is not my name". In this situation also the code will replace "is" with "is not". And the output will be "Good morning this is not not my name". You can consider this solution where we can check whether it's already "is not" or not.

(I am assuming here that you just want to correct "is" to "is not" and if you user types "is not" then you will not change anything. If this what you want then here is the correct code.)

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        String word=sc.nextLine();
        if(!word.contains("is not"))
            sb.append(word.replace("is","is not"));
        else sb.append(word);
        sb.append("\n"); //new line to get same string as 
                        // user's input 
    }
    sc.close();
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

If you want to use the earlier solution then you have to put a condition to check whether the user has already given a correct input or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` method for replace substrings.
But anyway if you don't need to replace parts of other words, you just should write `" is "` in brackets with spaces.

Comment: @GBlodgett because replace method won't be matched with substrings, e.g. "thIS" won't be replaced

Answer (score 0):

this worked

```
 if(word.equals("is")) {
        chaine=chaine.replaceFirst(" "+word+" ", " is not ");
}
```

replace function replaces all the occurences of the word you give, and you are giving it "is" which is included in "this", just put some spaces to prevent this. Using replace first will replace the first occurence, instead of replace which replaces everything.

even if using Scanner it self seems not to be a right practice

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Java's Scanner class and utilizing the [Scanner#next()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm) method in conjunction with the [Scanner#hasNext()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnext.htm) method you can expect to retrieve each word within the string as a token for each iteration of your **while** loop.

This is a better mechanism for what you are trying to do (with Scanner) when specifically utilizing the [String#replace()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replace) method because the [Scanner#next()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm) method retrieves each word on its own based on the default White-Space delimiter (since you have not specified a delimiter using the [Scanner#useDelimiter()](https://www.javatpoint.com/post/java-scanner-usedelimiter-method) method - *Note this: more later*).

As you may already know the [String#replace()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replace) method will replace **all** occurrences of a substring within a string whether it's inside a word or the word itself so you don't want to play that card in this particular case.

Your problem is that you are using the [String#replace()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replace) method against the **entire** string rather than just the found word itself:

```
if(word.equals("is")) {
    chaine = chaine.replace(word, "is not");
}
```

This will of course replace all occurrences of the substring `is` throughout the entire String (including in the word "th**is**" which is obviously not desired. It should be:

```
if(word.equals("is")) {
    word = word.replace(word, "is not");
}
```

and then append the contents of the **word** variable to a particular string build. You will need to rebuild the string as you are finished processing each word retrieved by the [Scanner#next()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm) method upon each iteration of the **while** loop.

For this small use case, to rebuild the string you can use the [String Concatenation Operator (**+**)](https://www.javatpoint.com/string-concatenation-in-java):

```
String finalString = ""; // Will hold the string build
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    String word = sc.next();
    if (word.equals("is")) {
        word = word.replace(word, "is not");
    }
    // Rebuild the string upon each iteration
    finalString+= (!finalString.equals("") ? " " + word : word);
}
```

In the code line above: `finalString+= (finalString.equals("") ? word : " " + word);` you can see the use of the String Concatenation Operator (**+**): `finalString+=` but there is also an equals character after it. This is basically telling the compiler that **finalyString** is to hold and maintain the string data that is already contained within it, in other words: `finalyString = finallyString +`.

In the above code line you can also see the use of a [Ternary Operator](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/ternary-operator.html) so as to apply white-spaces where needed:

```
(finalString+= (!finalString.equals("") ? " " + word : word);
```

A ternary operator works in the very same fashion as an **if/else** scenario. Using **if/else** it would look like:

```
// If finalString is NOT empty
if (!finalString.equals("") {
    // Append a white-space and then the word
    finalString+= " " + word;
} 
// otherwise if finalString is empty
else {
    // Just append the word 
    finalString+= word;
}
```

You can quickly see why using a Ternary Operator is a good way to go.

Another way you can rebuild the string is by utilizing the [StringBuilder](https://www.javatpoint.com/StringBuilder-class) class. It is good to use this class for building lots of strings through lots of iterations. It's good to get into the habit of using this class even for small situations like this:

```
String chaine = "good morning this is my name";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(chaine);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    String word = sc.next();
    if (word.equals("is")) {
        word = word.replace(word, "is not");
    }
    /* If the 'string build' is not empty then add
       a white-space in preperation for next word. */
    if (!sb.toString().equals("")) {
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    // Append next word (modified or not)
    sb.append(word);
}
chaine = sb.toString();
```

This is all fine and good but there is one little problem with all of this. What if the main string supplied has padded or additional white-spaces in specific locations along that String we want to remain? The above build examples remove them.

The [Scanner#hasNext()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnext.htm) with the [Scanner#next()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm) ignores all white-spaces when each token (word) is retrieved. This can actually be a major problem in a **lot** of situations but not all is lost since there is a simple fix.

Remember that [Scanner#useDelimiter()](https://www.javatpoint.com/post/java-scanner-usedelimiter-method) method we touched on earlier? Well, use it:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(chaine).useDelimiter(" ");
```

Now white-spaces will not be ignored and are retrieved as Null Strings (**""**) and processed within our code with:

```
// In the String Concatenation Operator code
finalString+= (!finalString.equals("") ? " " + word : word);

                O R

// In the StringBuilder code
if (!sb.toString().equals("")) {
    sb.append(" ");
}
```

But this does not take care of **Leading** white-spaces in the main string. To take care of **Leading** white-spaces we need to add a wee bit more code:

```
// In the String Concatenation Operator code
finalString+= (!finalString.equals("") || word.equals("") ? " " + word : word);

                O R

// In the StringBuilder code
if (!sb.toString().equals("") || word.equals("")) {
    sb.append(" ");
}
```

There, done....but you know, you can accomplish the same thing with a single line of code using the [String#replaceAll()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replaceall) method:

```
String chaine = "good morning this is my name";

// A Single line of code (all whitespaces remain intact).
chaine = chaine.replaceAll("\\bis\\b", "is not");
```

The [String#replaceAll()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replaceall) method allows for [Regular Expressions](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (**RegEx**) to be utilized arguably making life soooo much easier in a lot of cases.

The regular expression (`"\\bis\\b"`) passed to the **replaceAll()** method above contains the Word Boundary meta character **\b** which checks if a string or substring pattern begins and ends on a word boundary and the word within the expression is of course "**is**". You can read about [Boundary Matchers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) here. If you want to play around with Regular Expressions and test them then you can do it at [RegEx101.com](https://regex101.com/).